# Extract the site/domain name from a url in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to browse my Chrome history file using sqlite3 as per https://superuser.com/questions/602252/can-chrome-browser-history-be-exported-to-an-html-file.  I'm operating on a copy of the History database.

I want to be able to organize the urls by site using sqlite3 functions.  I'm trying to figure out how to extract the site (domain name) from the url column.

Once I know the magic function, I plan to use this so I can write queries over the site column.

```
ALTER TABLE urls ADD COLUMN site TEXT;
UPDATE urls SET site = ...;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far I have

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(SUBSTR(url, INSTR(url, '//') + 2), 0, INSTR(SUBSTR(url, INSTR(url, '//') + 2), '/')) AS site 
FROM urls;
```

It seems to work but is quite clunky.  Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formulation which correctly handles it when some URLs don't have the `http(s)://` or a final `/`.

The first version uses sub-selects:

```sql
select *, CASE when INSTR(domstage1, '/') > 0 then substr(domstage1, 1, instr(domstage1, '/')-1) else domstage1 end as domain 
from (select *, CASE when INSTR(url, '//') > 0 then substr(url, INSTR(url, '//')+2) else url end as domstage1 from urls);
```

I find this second CTE-based version more manageable and readable. I'm also using the more compact `IIF()` (added in sqlite 3.32) instead of `CASE`.

```sql
with
  stage1 as (select url, INSTR(url, '//') as idx_ss from logs where url is not NULL),
  stage2 as (select *, IIF(idx_ss > 0, SUBSTR(url, idx_ss+2), url) as dom1 from stage1),
  stage3 as (select *, INSTR(dom1, '/') as idx_s from stage2),
  stage4 as (select *, IIF(idx_s > 0, SUBSTR(dom1, 1, idx_s-1), dom1) as domain from stage3)
select domain from stage4;
```

From timings with a small database of about 5000 rows, they seem to perform about the same.